# Most Efficient way to permanently monitor multiples NAS folders using Powershell

Tags: powershell, monitoring

I have a problem and so far I can't find a proper way to monitor multiples NAS folders using Powershell. Basically, I want to permanently monitor a NAS folder (NOT local drive) and when a file is created or dragged to that folder, trigger a second batch to change the content of the file created.

My first option was to use FileSystemWatcher. It works fine with NAS folders but I have to keep the session open in order to keep the monitoring running.

```
PROCESS
{
   foreach  ($item in  $paths)
   { 
      
       $fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $path, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false}
        Register-ObjectEvent $fsw created -SourceIdentifier ($item + " folderMonitored") -Action     { 
            #Do something when a file is created
        }
    }
}
```

My second option was to create a permanent Event using WMI. Below script is monitoring C:\Test and if a file is created then it will trigger LaunchPowerShell.vbs. This is working fine but it does not work with NAS paths.

```
$computer = "edlt"
$filterNS = "root\cimv2"
$wmiNS = "root\subscription"
$query = @"
 Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 30 
 where targetInstance isa 'Cim_DirectoryContainsFile' 
 and targetInstance.GroupComponent = 'Win32_Directory.Name="c:\\\\test"'
"@
$filterName = "NewFile"
$scriptFileName = "C:\fso\LaunchPowerShell.vbs"

$filterPath = Set-WmiInstance -Class __EventFilter `
 -ComputerName $computer -Namespace $wmiNS -Arguments `
  @{name=$filterName; EventNameSpace=$filterNS; QueryLanguage="WQL";
    Query=$query}


$consumerPath = Set-WmiInstance -Class ActiveScriptEventConsumer 
 -ComputerName $computer -Namespace $wmiNS `
 -Arguments @{name="CleanupFileNames"; ScriptFileName=$scriptFileName;
  ScriptingEngine="VBScript"}

Set-WmiInstance -Class __FilterToConsumerBinding -ComputerName $computer 
  -Namespace $wmiNS -arguments @{Filter=$filterPath; Consumer=$consumerPath} |
  out-null
```

Is there any solution to monitor permanently a NAS folder using Powershell?

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it works on local drives how about creating a PSDrive Mapped drive and reference that in your code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7

Comment: Thanks RetiredGeek for that but unfortunately the reference states the following: "Because temporary drives are known only to PowerShell, you can't access them by using File Explorer, **Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)**, Component Object Model (COM), Microsoft .NET Framework, or with tools such as net use." Thanks Anyway!